# How do you name this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A = \{a, b, c... z\}$

How should I name this set?
My answer is "$A$ is the set of all letters in the alphabet"

Is "the alphabet" specific enough since it only specify that the first $3$ letter is "$a, b, c$" and the last is "$z$" and they are a few alphabet from different language that has the same format.

Is the "alphabet" specifc enough or should I use "english alphabet?"

Comment: Maybe the set of all lower case letters in the [English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet)? Whenever one writes down something like $A=\{a,b,c,\cdots,z\}$, the *context* should be clear.

Comment: How about $$\bigcup_{i=0061}^{007A}\{'U+'\frown 'i'\}$$

Comment: Do you mean to ask "what can I call it so that there is no ambiguity at all?" (this is what the answers so far seem to address), or do you mean to ask "how specific do I have to be in practice so that I avoid any reasonable misunderstanding?" (which is how I interpreted your question).

Answer (score 1):

You should say "the set of all lowercase letters in the Latin (or English) alphabet". You seem to be wanting to exclude uppercase letters, so you should specify that. Also, not only do other languages have different alphabets, but "alphabet" is also a technical term used in formal language theory with a more specific meaning that is not intended here.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the set of all lower case letters in the english alphabet.

assuming $\{A\} \neq \{a\}$.

But in case someone uses this definition mathematically, then what is an *alphabet* it needs to be defined properly.

> In formal language theory, a string is defined as a finite sequence of members of an underlying base set; this set is called the **alphabet**

Comment: "Small caps" is not the same as "lower case".

Comment: thanks for pointing out :-)